# Cannot deploy local Spark job, worker fails with EndPointAssociationError

Tags: scala, akka, apache-spark

I downloaded Spark 1.1.0, and build it with "sbt assembly". I attempt to run the example [Spark-Cassandra project](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/0_quick_start.md):

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import com.datastax.spark.connector._

object Test {
  def main (args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf(true)
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")

    val sc = new SparkContext("spark://127.0.0.1:7077", "test", conf)

    val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("test", "kv")
    println(rdd.count)
    println(rdd.first)
    println(rdd.map(_.getInt("value")).sum)
  }
}
```

The spark master is started by executing the ./start-master.sh in the sbin directory.
Then start a slave on the same machine with the command:

./start-slave.sh 0  spark://127.0.0.1:7077

Where the spark://.. address is the one fetched from localhost:8080 (spark dashboard).

This is all fine, the dashboard sees the worker. Then I run the Scala program, and get a ClassNotFoundException. This seems to be a bit misleading, as the worker logs report this error:

```
14/10/29 12:23:05 ERROR EndpointWriter: AssociationError [akka.tcp://sparkWorker@localhost:33137] -> [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@localhost:37279]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tcp://#
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@localhost:37279]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:37279
]
```

When I start the example program there is this warning:

```
14/10/29 12:22:31 WARN util.Utils: Your hostname, bas-HP-EliteBook-8530w resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 192.168.122.1 instead (on interface virbr0)
14/10/29 12:22:31 WARN util.Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
```

I don't know why this warning is there. My hosts file is as follows:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   bas-HP-EliteBook-8530w

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

conf/spark-env.sh has these options enabled:

```
SPARK_LOCAL_IP=127.0.0.1
SPARK_MASTER_IP=127.0.0.1
```

Full worker log:

```
Spark Command: java -cp ::/home/bas/Downloads/spark-1.1.0.backup/conf:/home/bas/Downloads/spark-1.1.0.backup/assembly/target/scala-2.10/spark-assembly-1.1.0-hadoop1.0.4.jar -XX:MaxPermSize#
========================================

Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
14/10/29 12:21:16 INFO Worker: Registered signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
14/10/29 12:21:16 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: bas,
14/10/29 12:21:16 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: bas,
14/10/29 12:21:16 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(bas, ); users with modify permissions: Set(bas, )
14/10/29 12:21:17 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
14/10/29 12:21:17 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
14/10/29 12:21:17 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkWorker@localhost:33137]
14/10/29 12:21:17 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkWorker' on port 33137.
14/10/29 12:21:17 INFO Worker: Starting Spark worker localhost:33137 with 2 cores, 2.8 GB RAM 
14/10/29 12:21:17 INFO Worker: Spark home: /home/bas/Downloads/spark-1.1.0.backup
14/10/29 12:21:17 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'WorkerUI' on port 8081.
14/10/29 12:21:17 INFO WorkerWebUI: Started WorkerWebUI at http://localhost:8081
14/10/29 12:21:17 INFO Worker: Connecting to master spark://127.0.0.1:7077...
14/10/29 12:21:18 INFO Worker: Successfully registered with master spark://127.0.0.1:7077
14/10/29 12:22:34 INFO Worker: Asked to launch executor app-20141029122234-0000/0 for test
14/10/29 12:22:35 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "java" "-cp" "::/home/bas/Downloads/spark-1.1.0.backup/conf:/home/bas/Downloads/spark-1.1.0.backup/assembly/target/scala-2.10/spark-a#
14/10/29 12:23:05 INFO Worker: Asked to kill executor app-20141029122234-0000/0
14/10/29 12:23:05 INFO ExecutorRunner: Runner thread for executor app-20141029122234-0000/0 interrupted
14/10/29 12:23:05 INFO ExecutorRunner: Killing process!
14/10/29 12:23:05 INFO Worker: Executor app-20141029122234-0000/0 finished with state KILLED exitStatus 1
14/10/29 12:23:05 INFO LocalActorRef: Message [akka.remote.transport.ActorTransportAdapter$DisassociateUnderlying] from Actor[akka://sparkWorker/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://sparkWorker/sy#
14/10/29 12:23:05 ERROR EndpointWriter: AssociationError [akka.tcp://sparkWorker@localhost:33137] -> [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@localhost:37279]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tcp://#
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@localhost:37279]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:37279
]
14/10/29 12:23:05 ERROR EndpointWriter: AssociationError [akka.tcp://sparkWorker@localhost:33137] -> [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@localhost:37279]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tcp://#
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@localhost:37279]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:37279
]
14/10/29 12:23:05 ERROR EndpointWriter: AssociationError [akka.tcp://sparkWorker@localhost:33137] -> [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@localhost:37279]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tcp://#
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@localhost:37279]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:37279
]
```

Full master log:

```
park Command: java -cp ::/home/bas/Downloads/spark-1.1.0.backup/conf:/home/bas/Downloads/spark-1.1.0.backup/assembly/target/scala-2.10/spark-assembly-1.1.0-hadoop1.0.4.jar -XX:MaxPermSize#
========================================

Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
14/10/29 12:20:52 INFO Master: Registered signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
14/10/29 12:20:52 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: bas,
14/10/29 12:20:52 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: bas,
14/10/29 12:20:52 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(bas, ); users with modify permissions: Set(bas, )
14/10/29 12:20:53 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
14/10/29 12:20:53 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
14/10/29 12:20:53 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkMaster@127.0.0.1:7077]
14/10/29 12:20:53 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkMaster' on port 7077.
14/10/29 12:20:54 INFO Master: Starting Spark master at spark://127.0.0.1:7077
14/10/29 12:20:54 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'MasterUI' on port 8080.
14/10/29 12:20:54 INFO MasterWebUI: Started MasterWebUI at http://localhost:8080
14/10/29 12:20:54 INFO Master: I have been elected leader! New state: ALIVE
14/10/29 12:21:18 INFO Master: Registering worker localhost:33137 with 2 cores, 2.8 GB RAM 
14/10/29 12:22:34 INFO Master: Registering app test
14/10/29 12:22:34 INFO Master: Registered app test with ID app-20141029122234-0000
14/10/29 12:22:34 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20141029122234-0000/0 on worker worker-20141029122117-localhost-33137
14/10/29 12:23:05 INFO Master: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.122.1:40211 got disassociated, removing it. 
14/10/29 12:23:05 INFO Master: Removing app app-20141029122234-0000
14/10/29 12:23:05 INFO LocalActorRef: Message [akka.remote.transport.ActorTransportAdapter$DisassociateUnderlying] from Actor[akka://sparkMaster/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://sparkMaster/sy#
14/10/29 12:23:05 INFO Master: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.122.1:40211 got disassociated, removing it. 
14/10/29 12:23:05 ERROR EndpointWriter: AssociationError [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@127.0.0.1:7077] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.122.1:40211]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tcp:/#
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.122.1:40211]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: Connection refused: /192.168.122.1:40211
]
14/10/29 12:23:05 INFO Master: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.122.1:40211 got disassociated, removing it. 
14/10/29 12:23:05 INFO Master: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.122.1:40211 got disassociated, removing it. 
14/10/29 12:23:05 ERROR EndpointWriter: AssociationError [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@127.0.0.1:7077] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.122.1:40211]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tcp:/#
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.122.1:40211]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: Connection refused: /192.168.122.1:40211
]
14/10/29 12:23:05 ERROR EndpointWriter: AssociationError [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@127.0.0.1:7077] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.122.1:40211]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tcp:/#
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.122.1:40211]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: Connection refused: /192.168.122.1:40211
]
14/10/29 12:23:05 INFO Master: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.122.1:40211 got disassociated, removing it. 
14/10/29 12:23:05 WARN Master: Got status update for unknown executor app-20141029122234-0000/0
```

IntelliJ stacktrace:

```
/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain Test
    14/10/29 12:22:31 WARN util.Utils: Your hostname, bas-HP-EliteBook-8530w resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 192.168.122.1 instead (on interface virbr0)
    14/10/29 12:22:31 WARN util.Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
    14/10/29 12:22:31 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: bas,
    14/10/29 12:22:31 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: bas,
    14/10/29 12:22:31 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(bas, ); users with modify permissions: Set(bas, )
    14/10/29 12:22:31 INFO slf4j.Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
    14/10/29 12:22:31 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
    14/10/29 12:22:32 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.122.1:40211]
    14/10/29 12:22:32 INFO Remoting: Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.122.1:40211]
    14/10/29 12:22:32 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 40211.
    14/10/29 12:22:32 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
    14/10/29 12:22:32 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
    14/10/29 12:22:32 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/spark-local-20141029122232-f3bf
    14/10/29 12:22:32 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'Connection manager for block manager' on port 34325.
    14/10/29 12:22:32 INFO network.ConnectionManager: Bound socket to port 34325 with id = ConnectionManagerId(192.168.122.1,34325)
    14/10/29 12:22:32 INFO storage.MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 470.3 MB
    14/10/29 12:22:32 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
    14/10/29 12:22:32 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterActor: Registering block manager 192.168.122.1:34325 with 470.3 MB RAM
    14/10/29 12:22:32 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
    14/10/29 12:22:32 INFO spark.HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /tmp/spark-eea6f1f3-8f69-4900-87c7-6da17f1f3d76
    14/10/29 12:22:32 INFO spark.HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
    14/10/29 12:22:32 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.1.14.v20131031
    14/10/29 12:22:32 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:33688
    14/10/29 12:22:32 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 33688.
    14/10/29 12:22:33 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.1.14.v20131031
    14/10/29 12:22:33 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040
    14/10/29 12:22:33 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
    14/10/29 12:22:33 INFO ui.SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://192.168.122.1:4040
    14/10/29 12:22:33 INFO client.AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master spark://127.0.0.1:7077...
    14/10/29 12:22:33 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
    14/10/29 12:22:34 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Connected to Spark cluster with app ID app-20141029122234-0000
    14/10/29 12:22:34 INFO client.AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20141029122234-0000/0 on worker-20141029122117-localhost-33137 (localhost:33137) with 2 cores
    14/10/29 12:22:34 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20141029122234-0000/0 on hostPort localhost:33137 with 2 cores, 512.0 MB RAM
    14/10/29 12:22:34 INFO client.AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20141029122234-0000/0 is now RUNNING
    14/10/29 12:22:34 INFO cql.CassandraConnector: Connected to Cassandra cluster: Test Cluster
    14/10/29 12:22:34 INFO core.Cluster: New Cassandra host /127.0.0.1:9042 added
    14/10/29 12:22:34 INFO cql.LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Adding host 127.0.0.1 (datacenter1)
    14/10/29 12:22:34 INFO cql.LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Adding host 127.0.0.1 (datacenter1)
    14/10/29 12:22:34 INFO cql.LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Adding host 127.0.0.1 (datacenter1)
    14/10/29 12:22:34 INFO cql.LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Adding host 127.0.0.1 (datacenter1)
    14/10/29 12:22:35 INFO cql.CassandraConnector: Disconnected from Cassandra cluster: Test Cluster
    14/10/29 12:22:35 INFO spark.SparkContext: Starting job: count at Test.scala:23
    14/10/29 12:22:35 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (count at Test.scala:23) with 1 output partitions (allowLocal=false)
    14/10/29 12:22:35 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Final stage: Stage 0(count at Test.scala:23)
    14/10/29 12:22:35 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
    14/10/29 12:22:35 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
    14/10/29 12:22:35 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting Stage 0 (CassandraRDD[0] at RDD at CassandraRDD.scala:47), which has no missing parents
    14/10/29 12:22:36 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(4224) called with curMem=0, maxMem=493187235
    14/10/29 12:22:36 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 4.1 KB, free 470.3 MB)
    14/10/29 12:22:36 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(2338) called with curMem=4224, maxMem=493187235
    14/10/29 12:22:36 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.3 KB, free 470.3 MB)
    14/10/29 12:22:36 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 192.168.122.1:34325 (size: 2.3 KB, free: 470.3 MB)
    14/10/29 12:22:36 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_0_piece0
    14/10/29 12:22:36 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from Stage 0 (CassandraRDD[0] at RDD at CassandraRDD.scala:47)
    14/10/29 12:22:36 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
    14/10/29 12:22:38 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Registered executor: Actor[akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@localhost:37279/user/Executor#2049453845] with ID 0
    14/10/29 12:22:38 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, NODE_LOCAL, 23151 bytes)
    14/10/29 12:22:38 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterActor: Registering block manager localhost:37704 with 265.4 MB RAM
    14/10/29 12:22:39 INFO network.ConnectionManager: Accepted connection from [192.168.122.1/192.168.122.1:36717]
    14/10/29 12:22:39 INFO network.SendingConnection: Initiating connection to [localhost/127.0.0.1:37704]
    14/10/29 12:22:39 INFO network.SendingConnection: Connected to [localhost/127.0.0.1:37704], 1 messages pending
    14/10/29 12:22:39 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on localhost:37704 (size: 2.3 KB, free: 265.4 MB)
    14/10/29 12:22:40 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.CassandraPartition
            java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
            java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
            java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
            java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
            java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
            java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
            org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:59)
            java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
            java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
            java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
            java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
            java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
            java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
            java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
            java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
            java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
            org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:62)
            org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:87)
            org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:159)
            java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
            java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
            java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    14/10/29 12:22:40 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, localhost, NODE_LOCAL, 23151 bytes)
    14/10/29 12:22:40 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) on executor localhost: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException (com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.CassandraPartition) [duplicate 1]
    14/10/29 12:22:40 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, localhost, NODE_LOCAL, 23151 bytes)
    14/10/29 12:22:40 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) on executor localhost: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException (com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.CassandraPartition) [duplicate 2]
    14/10/29 12:22:40 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, localhost, NODE_LOCAL, 23151 bytes)
    14/10/29 12:22:40 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) on executor localhost: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException (com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.CassandraPartition) [duplicate 3]
    14/10/29 12:22:40 ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
    14/10/29 12:22:40 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
    14/10/29 12:22:40 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0
    14/10/29 12:22:40 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Failed to run count at Test.scala:23
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, localhost): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.CassandraPartition
            java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
            java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
            java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
            java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
            java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
            java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
            org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:59)
            java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
            java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
            java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
            java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
            java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
            java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
            java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
            java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
            java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
            org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:62)
            org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:87)
            org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:159)
            java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
            java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
            java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1185)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1174)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1173)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1173)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1391)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

build.sbt:

```
name := "sparktest"

version := "1.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.1.0-alpha3" withSources() withJavadoc()

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core" % "1.1.0"
```

Scala-compiler version = 2.10.4

Java version = 1.7.0_67

I tried setting the spark local IP as such:

```
System.setProperty("SPARK_LOCAL_IP", "127.0.0.1")
println(System.getenv("SPARK_LOCAL_IP"))
```

and like this:

```
scala.util.Properties.envOrElse("SPARK_LOCAL_IP", "127.0.0.1")
println(System.getenv("SPARK_LOCAL_IP"))
```

But it merely prints null.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

**Edit:** Changing the spark config as follows solves the issue:

```
val conf = new SparkConf(true)
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
      .set("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "/home/bas/Downloads/spark-cassandra-connector/spark-cassandra-connector-java/target/scala-2.10/spark-cassandra-connector-java-assembly-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar")
```

Note that this didn't work with the SBT jar file of the spark-cassandra-connector, I had to build it from source. In fact, I removed all SBT dependencies and added the spark dependency as a source build as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error is because Spark doesn't have `spark-cassandra-connector` on worker's classpath.

You can either use one of [one-jar](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Community-Plugins.html#One+jar+plugins) sbt plugins like `sbt-assembly` to create `assembled jar` including all dependencies. And use it [to submit](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) your job to Spark:

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class <main-class>
  --master <master-url> \
  <assembled jar> \
  [application-arguments]
```

Or you can use Spark's [Runtime Environment](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment) option `spark.executor.extraClassPath` and set classpath for your application globally.

Comment: It worked :-). I will edit the original question with the adjusted code. I had to manually build the spark-cassandra-connector library from source, as the jar file generated by SBT didn't seem to work. Thanks!